# Camel - Kafka - additionalProperties issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am having issue with setting additionalProperties. I am setting the property as below

```
Map<String, String> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();
        additionalProperties.put("sasl.login.callback.handler.class",
         "io.confluent.kafka.clients.plugins.auth.token.TokenUserLoginCallbackHandler");
```

Followed by the Kafka route builder is setup as below

```
.additionalProperties(additionalProperties)
```

However the property i see populated in the kafka config show up as
"sasl"->"io.confluent.kafka.clients.plugins.auth.token.TokenUserLoginCallbackHandler"

The reason being the PropertyBindingSupport.java is splitting by dot

// we should only walk and create OGNL path for the middle graph

```
String[] parts;
if (isDotKey(name)) {
    parts = splitKey(name);
} else {
    parts = new String[] { name };
}
```

// which only picks up "sasl" instead of "sasl.login.callback-handler.class"

```
newName = parts[i + 1];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by upgrading camel-kafka from 3.7.0 to 3.8.0 wherein this issues has been fixed on endpoint property resolution.

Refer : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16043